# Lucene: detecting missing spaces

Tags: lucene, search-engine, lucene.net

I'm writing a search engine with Lucene.net for a database of ~ 2 million products. I'm using the `Snowball Analyzer` and so far I've been really impressed with the performance and result sets.

The one issue I can't seem to overcome is detecting missing spaces in search inputs.

For Example:

***A User is looking for 'Black Diamond' brand products but they search for 'blackdiamond'.***

Since the snowball analyzer creates two separate `Tokens` for Black Diamond I get **0** results.

What approach can I take to correct this issue?  I've looked a bit into the `Shingle Analyzer`(n-gram) but not sure if that would help.

Is it possible to combine a `Shingle Analyzer` with the `SpellChecker` (and would that be an effect solution)?  It would be idea if I could just prompt people with a ***Did You Mean: 'Black Diamond'?*** link when this occurs.

Comment: take a look at lucene 4.0 WordBreakSpellChecker https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-3523. If its easy to port it, that would be an easy solution

Comment: i'll give it a try.  I bet it had other dependencies on 4.0 tho. I'm running 3.0 but maybe I can replicate the concept.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about initially running the user query as is, if there are no results (or score is below a certain threshold), run N additional searches (where N is the number of possibilities to break the word in two) showing the user results for the possibility that received the highest score.

Comment: I don't think that would work very well, mainly due to the data set being very large.  If I understand correclty your saying to split the word at every possible index.  So the first iteration would yield tokens:  'b' & 'lackdiamond'.  Their are products with the single letter b in them so this returns invalid results.  I really need a way to create a token for phrases with spaces and match against them.

Comment: I was thinking running 'b' *AND* 'lackdiamond' which will most likely won't return nothing, while the fifth iteration for: 'black' AND 'diamond' option is expected to return results. But who says you want to limit the user to a conjunction to begin with, so I guess my suggestion is a more of a mediocre hack in case you don't want to invest in a dedicate spell checking solution. I stand corrected. Thanks.